# Yeoman recursive prompt, callback doesn't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

Im pretty new to Yeoman, but im trying to acomplish a recursive prompt. Inspired by the EntityGenerator in jhipster (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/master/generators/entity).

However there seems to be an error somewhere preventing the loop to happen.

My code is as follows:

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');

var inputFields = [];

module.exports = yeoman.Base.extend({
  prompting: {
    askForName: askForName,
    askForFields: askForFields
  }
});

function askForData() {
  var prompts = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'name',
    message: 'Name?',
    default: 'Slim Shady'
  }];

  return this.prompt(prompts).then(function (props) {
    this.props = props;
    this.async();
  }.bind(this));
}

function askForFields() {
  var cb = this.async();
  askForField.call(this, cb);
}

function askForField(cb) {
  var prompts = [{
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'fieldAdd',
    message: 'Do you want to add a field?',
    default: true
  }, {
    when: function (response) {
      return response.fieldAdd === true;
    },
    type: 'input',
    name: 'fieldName',
    message: 'What is the name of your field?'
  };

  this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
    this.log("Done prompting: ", props);
    if (props.fieldAdd) {
      var field = {
        fieldName: props.fieldName,
      };
      inputFields.push(field);
    }
    if (props.fieldAdd) {
      askForField.call(that, cb);
    } else {
      cb();
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

The first loop of the recursive prompt is working as intended, but the logging `this.log("Done prompting: ", props);` never executes. Its like the callback of the prompt never happens. The generator just exits after one run.

I have logged and compared the `this`-s of all functions and they are the same. I have looked at many similar stackoverflow questions, but i cannot see anything wrong except that it doesnt work.

Any help or tips is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using yeoman-generator v0.23.0 and up.

According to the release of yeoman-generator v0.23.0 (https://github.com/yeoman/generator/releases/tag/v0.23.0):

> Base#prompt() functions now returns a promise instead of taking a
>   callback parameter. That'll make it easier to use inside asynchronous
>   tasks.

```
prompting: function () {
   return this.prompt(questions).then(function (answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
  }.bind(this));
}
```

This is due to the release of Inquirer.js v1.0.0 (https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0):

> The whole inquirer API is now based on promises!
>
> - The base API interface is now inquirer.prompt(questions).then().
>     There's no more callback function.
> - Any async question functions is taking a promise as return value
>     instead of requiring this.async().

---

## Solution

Into your askForField() function, you have to replace:

```
this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
    this.log("Done prompting: ", props);
    if (props.fieldAdd) {
        var field = {
            fieldName: props.fieldName,
        };
        inputFields.push(field);
    }
    if (props.fieldAdd) {
        askForField.call(that, cb);
    } else {
        cb();
    }
}.bind(this));
```

by:

```
return this.prompt(prompts).then(function (props) {
    this.log("Done prompting: ", props);
    if (props.fieldAdd) {
        var field = {
            fieldName: props.fieldName,
        };
        inputFields.push(field);
    }
    if (props.fieldAdd) {
        askForField.call(that, cb);
    } else {
        cb();
    }
}.bind(this));
```

as you did it into your askForData() function :

```
return this.prompt(prompts).then(function (props) {
    this.props = props;
    this.async();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, had the project on ice for a while since i got stuck. Anyway, the solution worked perfectly, thanks a lot!